# how to get value of a matching text field in shell script

Tags: shell, file, sed, printing, find-occurrences

I want to capture the first occurence value of a given text field by reading the whole file. How to achieve this in shell:

**Input line:**

```
<coverage lines-valid="3966"  lines-covered="2094"  line-rate="0.528"  branches-valid="5864"  branches-covered="1400"  branch-rate="0.23870000000000002"  timestamp="1532416636656" complexity="0" version="0.1">
```

I need to get value of first occurence of **line-rate** field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention you read a whole file, first `grep` the lines with "line-rate" in them:

```
grep "line-rate" input-file
```

Then you want only the first occurence:

```
grep "line-rate" input-file | head -1
```

And finally you want the "line-rate" value:

```
grep "line-rate" input-file | head -1 | sed 's/.*line-rate="\([0-9.]\+\)" .*/\1/'
```

Explanation of the sed:

- `.*` anything
- followed by `line-rate="`
- `[0-9.]`: characters 0 to 9 and the dot
- `\+`: at least one of the preceding, no maximum
- `\( \)`: delimit what I want to keep, here the numbers
- `.*`: everything that follows
- `\1`: replaced by what was enclosed by `\( \)`

So here it will take any number (with dot or not) that follows `line-rate="`, and ends with `"`.

Obviously, replace `input_file` by your file name.

This was done using bash, using GNU sed.

Comment: `grep -oP 'line-rate="\K[^"]+'  file |head -1`

Comment: Add it as an answer, it's much simpler than mine.